# The println() function calls System.out.println() internally. How?

Tags: kotlin

I'm aware that the println function in Kotlin calls System.out.println. My questions are:

1. Where this System.out.println come from? Is it Java code?
2. Does this shortcut (using println instead of System.out.println) affect performance? as it has to go to excute that method at first?

Comment: It just calls the normal `System.out.println` method. Here's the JVM source: https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/6a670dc5f38fc73eb01d754d8f7c158ae0176ceb/libraries/stdlib/jvm/src/kotlin/io/Console.kt#L79. The function is inlined, so there is no performance overhead compared to calling `System.out.println` directly.

Comment: @marstran so it is using java println? why that? Kotlin not having its own println function?

Comment: Because it runs on the JVM and it already has a println function? Why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: but isn't that owned by Java? I mean could Oracle become angry of JetBrains using their System.out.println?

Comment: "I mean could Oracle become angry of JetBrains using their System.out.println?". Just wait until they find out that Kotlin uses the JVM (Java Virtual Machine), but then wait until the C guys find out that the JVM is written in C++. I think you need to do a bit of research into how programming languages work in general.

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin doesn't necessarily call System.out.println, this is only true on the JVM.

The println() function delegates the printing to whatever output mechanism is deemed most appropriate on the target that it is running on, be it JVM, node, a web browser, native, iOS, ...

This is a perfectly normal way to go on about it, the alternative would be to reinvent low-level output stuff that is already there.

1. Yes
2. No, not on JVM at least as it is a one line inlined call